# Android SparseBooleanArray ArrayIndexOutOfBounds

Tags: java, android, android-sparsearray

My app has an SparseBooleanArray to store selected entries in a ListAdapter.
The array is initialized as empty in the constructor.

```
private SparseBooleanArray mSelectedItemsIds;

public TaskArrayAdapter(@NonNull Context context, @NonNull List<Task> objects) {
    super(context, R.layout.item_task, objects);
    mSelectedItemsIds = new SparseBooleanArray();
    Log.d("Booleansize", String.valueOf(mSelectedItemsIds.size()));
}
```

Now in the getView method I check, whether the current position is in the array or not:

```
if (mSelectedItemsIds.valueAt(position)) {
        convertView.setBackgroundColor(Color.BLUE);
        convertView.getBackground().setAlpha(100);
    } else {
```

The mSelectedItemsIds is not altered during my testing. I am inserting entries to the list. After exactly 12 entries it crashes on `mSelectedItemsIds.valueAt(position)` with ArrayIndexOutOfBound at 11.
On another device it crashes after 14 inserts.
The size of the array is always 0 before every check.

How is that possible?

Here are all relevant parts of the adapter class (I cut out On Click listener, that are never triggered)

```
public class TaskArrayAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Task> {
// Array with all selectedIds
private SparseBooleanArray mSelectedItemsIds;

public TaskArrayAdapter(@NonNull Context context, @NonNull List<Task> objects) {
    super(context, R.layout.item_task, objects);
    mSelectedItemsIds = new SparseBooleanArray();
    Log.d("Booleansize", String.valueOf(mSelectedItemsIds.size()));
}/**
 * Called for the ListView to get the view at position
 * @param position
 * @param convertView
 * @param parent
 * @return
 */
@NonNull
@Override
public View getView(final int position, @Nullable View convertView, @NonNull ViewGroup parent) {
    // Get the data item for this position
    final Task task = getItem(position);
    // Check if an existing view is being reused, otherwise inflate the view
    if (convertView == null) {
        convertView = LayoutInflater.from(getContext()).inflate(R.layout.item_task, parent, false);
    }
    // Lookup view for data population
    TextView tvDescription = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.tvDescription);
    TextView tvDueDate = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.tvDueDate);
    CheckBox cbDone = (CheckBox) convertView.findViewById(R.id.cbDone);
    // Populate the data into the template view using the data object
    tvDescription.setText(task.description);
    if (task.dueDate != null) {
        tvDueDate.setText(task.dueDate.toString());
    } else {
        tvDueDate.setText(R.string.no_due_date);
    }
    cbDone.setChecked(task.done);
    cbDone.setTag(position);
    convertView.setTag(position);

    // Set listeners
    cbDone.setOnClickListener(checkBoxListener);

    convertView.setOnClickListener(viewClickListener);

    convertView.setOnLongClickListener(viewLongClickListener);
    Log.d("Booleansize", String.valueOf(mSelectedItemsIds.size()));
    // check if the current item is selected for background color
    if (mSelectedItemsIds.valueAt(position)) {
        convertView.setBackgroundColor(Color.BLUE);
        convertView.getBackground().setAlpha(100);
    } else {
        convertView.setBackgroundColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);
        convertView.getBackground().setAlpha(255);
    }

    // Return the completed view to render on screen
    return convertView;
}/**
 * Change the isSelected value
 * @param position
 */
public void toggleSelection(int position) {
    selectView(position, !mSelectedItemsIds.get(position));
}

/**
 * Completely forget the current selection
 */
public void removeSelection() {
    mSelectedItemsIds = new SparseBooleanArray();
    notifyDataSetChanged();
}

/**
 * Set the select view to the given value
 * @param position
 * @param value
 */
public void selectView(int position, boolean value) {
    if (value) {
        mSelectedItemsIds.put(position, value);
    } else {
        mSelectedItemsIds.delete(position);
    }
    notifyDataSetChanged();
}

/**
 * get number of selected entries
 * @return
 */
public int getSelectedCount() {
    return mSelectedItemsIds.size();
}

public SparseBooleanArray getSelectedIds() {
    return mSelectedItemsIds;
}
```

Comment: where exactly are you `initializing mSelectedItemsIds` ??

Comment: `mSelectedItemsIds = new SparseBooleanArray();` in the TaskArrayAdapter. getView is called after every insert for every item in the list so far.

Comment: can u post your full adapter class??

Answer (score 0):

You probably meant to use `SparseBooleanArray.get` method:

> `boolean get (int key)`
>
> Gets the boolean mapped from the specified key, or false if no such mapping has been made.

Use like so:

```
if (mSelectedItemsIds.get(position)) {
    convertView.setBackgroundColor(Color.BLUE);
    convertView.getBackground().setAlpha(100);
} else {
    ....
}
```

`valueAt(int position)` on the other hand takes position within the array, that's from `0` to `size() - 1`. You can use that to iterate over all values within the array.

Comment: That makes sense! But how is it possible, that the first 11 inserts work? Is it possible that the internal array is initialized with size 10?

Comment: Yes that is definitly the solution. And it does solve my second problem, which is the wrong entries to be colored... Thank you really much

Comment: `Is it possible that the internal array is initialized with size 10?` According to source default capacity really is 10 items.